# Do you know how i can return object via mono webassembly

Tags: javascript, c#, mono, webassembly

I want to return c# object via mono-wasm, when i try to return, i get this object in my javascript file
[returned object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5F3p.png)

my C# code is in [image2]:
[C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvEpD.png)

my js code:
[JS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTp1S.png)

everything works fine when i try to return strings or any primitive objects

i hope that someone has idea over how i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an instance of `JSObject` and returning that instead.

```cs
public class Example {

    public static WebAssembly.JSObject ShowPerson(int age, string name, string firstName) {
        WebAssembly.JSObject Person = new WebAssembly.JSObject();
        Person.SetObjectProperty("age", age);
        Person.SetObjectProperty("name", name);
        Person.SetObjectProperty("firstName", firstName);
        return Person;
    }
}
```